# Postgres SELECT COUNT(*) + GROUP BY не выводит если 0 строк

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  status smallint
);

CREATE TABLE phones
(
  phone character varying,
  users integer[]
);
```

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT  phones.phone, COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM phones,items 
WHERE phones.phone = '8985545444' AND items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) AND items.status = 1 
GROUP BY phones.phone;
```

Если номер: 7924445588 - получаем:

```
   phone    | count
------------+-------
 7924445588 |     3
```

Если номер: 8985545444 - получаем пустоту:

```
 phone | count
-------+-------
```

Нужно чтобы было:

```
   phone    | count 
------------+-------
 8985545444 |     0
```

Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT
  phones.phone,
  coalesce(COUNT(*), 0)  AS "count"
FROM
  phones,
  items
WHERE
  phones.phone = '8985545444'
  AND items.user_id = ALL (phones.users)
  AND items.status = 1
GROUP BY
  phones.phone;
```

Comment: К сожалению не помагает - все равно пусто

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо использовать `LEFT JOIN` и считать только записи из таблицы items:

```
SELECT phones.phone, COUNT(items.*) AS "count"
FROM phones
LEFT JOIN items on items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) and items.status = 1
WHERE phones.phone = '8985545444'
GROUP BY phones.phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, группировка тут не нужна:

```
SELECT  '8985545444', COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM phones,items 
WHERE phones.phone = '8985545444' AND items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) 
AND items.status = 1
```

Comment: Проверяли? Если запрос не возвращает записей, то будет 0 (GROUP BY нет).

Answer (score -1):

Нужно использовать подзапрос:

```
SELECT phones.phone,
(select count(*) from items where items.status = 1 and items.user_id = ANY(phones.users)) as "Count" 
FROM phones 
WHERE phones.phone = ANY(Array['7924445588', '7890546789', '8985545444']);
```